# AND OR query with ObjectionJS, knex

Tags: mysql, orm, knex.js, objection.js

`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE AGE>40 AND (LOCATION='Chennai' OR NOT LOCATION='Agra');`

How to write something similar to the above query statement in ObjectionJS/Knex ORM ?

Comment: `LOCATION='Chennai' OR NOT LOCATION='Agra'` Why do you have OR in between these two?

Comment: *`LOCATION='Chennai' OR NOT LOCATION='Agra'`* - if 2nd condition part `NOT LOCATION='Agra'` is false/null then the 1st part `LOCATION='Chennai'` is false/null too. Hence 1st part is excess and must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE AGE>40 AND (LOCATION='Chennai' OR LOCATION <> 'Agra');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have model `Employee` then you can use Objection.js query

```
Employee.query()
        .select('*')
        .where('age', '>', 40)
        .where(builder => builder.where('location', 'Chennai')
                                 .orWhereNot('location', 'Agra')
        )
```

you can read more about Objection.js subqueries syntax here https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/subqueries.html